# What's the difference between export my api key as a module or put it in an .env file

Tags: node.js, encryption, dotenv

So I want to know what are the differences between using the module.exports to hide my api key inside another js file or by using .env then later use .gitignore for both. Because essentially both files won't be visible but what are the diffences?

Comment: It's a common practice to have all the sensitive data in one single .env file